# SWReveal ordinary push with back

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I have storyboard structure with `SWRevealViewController`. Everything works fine, setting view controllers etc. Now, I have one image on menu that leads to profile and is not in structure of `SWReveal`. Anybody knows any way of pushing it to *root navigation controller* and back button to lead back to `SWReveal`?

I have tried this:

```
RegistrationvViewController *vcSw = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editProfile"];
[self presentViewController:vcSw animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I embedded `SWReveal` in `NavigationController` and tried `performingSegueWithIdentifier` but back is not shown as well.

Comment: presentViewController is show model view,  you need to use sel.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller to push viewcontroller

Comment: I have used performSegueWithIdentifier, but same... Any idea?

Comment: question was still confusing , post image of storyboard

Answer (score 0):

//if you want to push from swreveal to any controller so you have to make a navigation controller

use this code

```
 UIStoryboard*Storyboard=[AppDelegate storyBoardType];
            yourController  *dashboard=(yourController*)[Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourControllerId"];

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dashboard];

            [navController setViewControllers: @[yourController] animated: YES];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
```

//back to the swreveal from controller

```
[self.revealViewController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.